# Optimizing MySql Query Performance

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm pulling data from 4 tables which are:

#### job_master

<kbd>**job_number**</kbd><kbd>**client**</kbd><kbd>**col3**</kbd><kbd>**col4**</kbd>
<kbd>123</kbd>                <kbd>45</kbd>      <kbd>blah</kbd> <kbd>blah</kbd> 
<kbd>456</kbd>                <kbd>12</kbd>      <kbd>blah</kbd> <kbd>blah</kbd>

#### accompaniment_common (f31 and f32 will contain 3 sets as there 3 in this table)

<kbd>**job_number**</kbd><kbd>**set_no**</kbd><kbd>**date_audit**</kbd>   <kbd>**column 4**</kbd><kbd>**column 5**</kbd><kbd>**column 3**</kbd>
<kbd>123</kbd>                <kbd>1</kbd>           <kbd>2013-04-23</kbd>   <kbd>blah blah</kbd>   <kbd>blah blah</kbd>  <kbd>blah blah</kbd>   
<kbd>456</kbd>                <kbd>2</kbd>           <kbd>2013-04-13</kbd>   <kbd>blah blah</kbd>   <kbd>blah blah</kbd>  <kbd>blah blah</kbd>   
<kbd>123</kbd>                <kbd>3</kbd>           <kbd>2013-04-10</kbd>   <kbd>blah blah</kbd>   <kbd>blah blah</kbd>  <kbd>blah blah</kbd>

#### f31

<kbd>**job_number**</kbd><kbd>**parameter**</kbd><kbd>**rating**</kbd><kbd>**comments**</kbd><kbd>**set_no**</kbd>
<kbd>123</kbd>                <kbd>1</kbd>                  <kbd>2</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>           
<kbd>123</kbd>                <kbd>2</kbd>                  <kbd>2</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>           
<kbd>123</kbd>                <kbd>3</kbd>                  <kbd>1</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>           
<kbd>456</kbd>                <kbd>1</kbd>                  <kbd>1</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>           
<kbd>456</kbd>                <kbd>2</kbd>                  <kbd>1</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>           
<kbd>456</kbd>                <kbd>3</kbd>                  <kbd>2</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>           
<kbd>123</kbd>                <kbd>1</kbd>                  <kbd>2</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>           
<kbd>123</kbd>                <kbd>2</kbd>                  <kbd>2</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>           
<kbd>123</kbd>                <kbd>3</kbd>                  <kbd>1</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>

#### f32

<kbd>**job_number**</kbd><kbd>**parameter**</kbd><kbd>**rating**</kbd><kbd>**comments**</kbd><kbd>**set_no**</kbd>
<kbd>123</kbd>                <kbd>1</kbd>                  <kbd>3</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>           
<kbd>123</kbd>                <kbd>2</kbd>                  <kbd>1</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>           
<kbd>123</kbd>                <kbd>3</kbd>                  <kbd>1</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>           
<kbd>456</kbd>                <kbd>1</kbd>                  <kbd>2</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>           
<kbd>456</kbd>                <kbd>2</kbd>                  <kbd>3</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>           
<kbd>456</kbd>                <kbd>3</kbd>                  <kbd>1</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>           
<kbd>123</kbd>                <kbd>1</kbd>                  <kbd>2</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>           
<kbd>123</kbd>                <kbd>2</kbd>                  <kbd>2</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>           
<kbd>123</kbd>                <kbd>3</kbd>                  <kbd>1</kbd>        <kbd>blah blah ble</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>

The query that I'm using is:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT job_number, set_no, SUM(IF(rating=1,1,0))  as f31yes, 
   SUM(if(rating=2,1,0))  as f31no FROM f31 GROUP BY job_number, set_no) x 

   JOIN 

   (SELECT job_number, set_no, SUM(IF(rating=1,1,0)) as f32yes, 
   SUM(IF(rating=2,1,0)) as f32no FROM f32 GROUP BY job_number, set_no) y       
   ON (x.job_number = y.job_number and x.set_no = y.set_no)

   JOIN 

   (SELECT date_audit, job_number, set_no FROM accompaniment_common) z
   ON (x.job_number = z.job_number and x.set_no = z.set_no) 

   JOIN

   (SELECT job_number, client FROM job_master) jm
   ON (z.job_number = jm.job_number)

   WHERE z.date_audit >= '2013-04-01' AND z.date_audit < '2013-05-01'
   AND jm.client = 45
   HAVING ((f31yes+f32yes)/(f31yes+f32yes+f31no+f32no)) >= 0.9
```

When I run this query in phpMyAdmin, the results are obtained within **2-3 seconds**. This seems like quick retrieval but when I put this inside a PHP file and execute it, it takes like **5-6 minutes** to complete.

Of course  I run it in a loop for different clients such as:

```
$clients = array(45,10,12,13,14,25,60,144);
$total = array();
foreach($clients as $client)
{
   $q = mysql_query(// the above query goes here);
   $numrows = mysql_num_rows($q);
   $total[$client] = $numrows;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

If I go by the time taken in phpMyAdmin, the whole process should be complete within 30 seconds, but it doesn't. This is baffling as I think I'm using the query in an appropriate way. Any suggestions?

PS : Yes, I'm aware that `mysql_*` are deprecated, but we took over this project from another company and don't have enough time to switch to `PDO` or `mysqli`

Comment: Did you try profiling the different parts of the php script?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure how one does that. Let me look into what profiling is.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running multiple queries (one per client), try running a single query for all required clients - like:

```
SELECT jm.job_number, 
       jm.client,
       ac.date_audit, 
       ac.set_no,
       count(distinct case f31.rating when 1 then f31.parameter end) f31yes,
       count(distinct case f31.rating when 2 then f31.parameter end) f31no,
       count(distinct case f32.rating when 1 then f32.parameter end) f32yes,
       count(distinct case f32.rating when 2 then f32.parameter end) f32no
FROM job_master jm
JOIN accompaniment_common ac ON jm.job_number = ac.job_number
JOIN f31 ON ac.job_number = f31.job_number and ac.set_no = f31.set_no
JOIN f32 ON ac.job_number = f32.job_number and ac.set_no = f32.set_no
WHERE ac.date_audit >= '2013-04-01' AND ac.date_audit < '2013-05-01' 
  AND jm.client in (45,10,12,13,14,25,60,144)
GROUP BY jm.job_number, ac.set_no
HAVING (f31yes+f32yes) / (f31yes+f32yes+f31no+f32no) >= 0.9
```

Comment: Could you explain what this line does `count(distinct case f31.rating when 1 then f31.parameter end) f31yes`? Is it same as `sum(if())`?

Comment: Yes and no - *in this case*, it should have the same effect as the equivalent `sum(if())` expression. `count(distinct ...)` returns the number of distinct values in the rest of the expression, within the group *excluding* nulls; `case` *expression* `when` *value* `then` *result* `else` *other result* `end` is an expression that evaluates to *result* when *expression=value*, otherwise it evaluates to *other result* (or NULL if no `else` clause is included). So `f31yes` is effectively counting the number of different `f31.parameter` values for each `job_number` and `set_no`, where `rating` is 1.

Comment: (Added GROUP BY clause to query.)

Answer (score 0):

Add index to your columns that are used in the JOINs.

```
ALTER TABLE f31 ADD INDEX (job_number);
ALTER TABLE f31 ADD INDEX (set_no);
ALTER TABLE f32 ADD INDEX (job_number);
ALTER TABLE f32 ADD INDEX (set_no);
ALTER TABLE accompaniment_common ADD INDEX (job_number);
ALTER TABLE accompaniment_common ADD INDEX (set_no);
ALTER TABLE job_master ADD INDEX (job_number);
```

For more info about database indexing, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work).